# Speed up numpy array broadcasting using array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I speed up this for-loop statement? Is it possible to use fast numpy [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) approach for this purpose?

```
np.random.seed(2021)
x = np.zeros((10, 3))
values = np.random.randn(10)
idxs = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10,))
for i, (idx, val) in enumerate(zip(idxs, values)):
    x[i, idx.item()] = val
print(x)

[[ 0.          0.          1.48860905]
 [ 0.          0.          0.67601087]
 [-0.41845137  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.80652081  0.        ]
 [ 0.55587583  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.70550429]
 [ 0.          0.          1.13085826]
 [ 0.64500184  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.10641374  0.        ]
 [ 0.42215483  0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to reach the same `x` such as in the provided example.

Comment: But what is the logic?

Comment: `idxs` contains indexes of columns which I want to update using `values`. That's it. In the mentioned code I've provided the naive approach how to tackle it. I suppose it can be faster using numpy broadcasting.

Comment: Just do: x[np.arange(len(idxs)), idxs] = values

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I'm looking for.
I missed `np.arange(len(idxs))` part and couldn't figure out what's wrong.